# What is the total of all the possible final scores that cannot be achieved in this game?

Tags: contest-math

> In a new game called Nooseball, you can only score points 2 ways. You can score 7 points for a "touchdown," and 3 points for a "field goal." What is the total of all the possible final scores that cannot be achieved in this game?

I'm having a really hard time with this problem. How can you solve this when you don't know what the maximum scores can be etc — I must be missing some crucial information. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Small hint: note that as soon as you find three consecutive scores that are achievable, all larger scores are as well (just keep scoring field goals).

Comment: Aha, thank you! But just to check would 31 be the right answer?

Comment: @Helena If by that you mean $1+2+4+5+8+11=31$, then yes

Comment: By the way, this is often called the Chicken McNugget problem.

Comment: @rogerl but if the numbers were different, say m and n where m<n, would I just need to find m consecutive scores that are achievable?

Comment: @Helena yes, thats right, assuming $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: This problem is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) (among many other places).